# PHP strings and concatenation

Tags: php, string, quotes

I have changed my code and now I have a new error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in
 /webroot/c/o/..../...../www/a/drop_down_car_test.php on line 19
```

here is the code:

```
<?php

//////connecting to our sql server
$db_connect=mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx")     or die("not logged in");
//////now selecting our database
$db_select=mysql_select_db("coden003_car") or die(mysql_error());
////this query is used the first time the page loads
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM car "); 

echo '<form action="drop_down_car_test.php?" method="GET">';
echo '<table border = \"1\">';
echo '<tr><td>id</td><td>car</td><td>name</td>';

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['id'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<select name='carDropDown." . $row['id'] . "' >";
<option value="1">ford</option>;  <---------line 19
<option value="2">toyota</option>;
<option value="3">gmc</option>;
</select>";
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['name'];
echo "</td><td>";
}////end while
echo"<table>";

echo '<td bgcolor=#7FFF00><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>';
echo "</form>";

?>
```

im use to C++ usage of quotes and PHP confuses me.

Comment: the html at the top should have a <?php ?> tag for the PHP part, and in your PHP code at the bottom, you have a syntax error in $_GET[]. what are you trying to do and what's "not working?"

Comment: The problem is how you output the `id_field` in your html, you must switch to php: `<select name="carDropDown<?php print $row['id_field']; ?>">`. When you have a problem like this try printing out the contents of the array to see what's going on: `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: That's a poor name for select, but what you want is `$_GET['carDropDown.$row[\'id_field'\]']`

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
echo '<select name="carDropDown.$row['id']">
```

You need to make it:

```
echo "<select name=\"carDropDown.{$row['id']}\">
```

You were not escaping the `'`, but also you can't use a variable inside single quotes, but you can use one inside double quotes (array calls must be wrapped in { and }).

And of course the closing `'` at the end of that string needs to be changed to `"`

And you're missing a semicolon at the end of that string.

And you didn't close the block (you forgot a closing `}`).

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
echo "<select name='carDropDown." . $row['id'] . "' >";
```

OR

```
echo "<select name=carDropDown.$row['id'] >";
```

---

In PHP you can CONCAT strings like this:

```
echo "hello" . "world" . $yourVariable . " Something else ";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the `<select>` name, which will make it a little easier to read on the `$_GET[]` is to make `carDropDown` an array with the `$row['id']` as the array key.

```
echo '<select name="carDropDown['.$row['id'].']">
```

Now on the php side you can do -

```
foreach ($row['id'] as $id){
$carName=$_GET['carDropDown'][$id]];
echo $carName;}
```